# Comparing all combinations of elements in a Collection via the Streams API

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm trying to compare all combinations(i.e. no duplicate comparisons) of elements in a `HashMap` and returning a List of all the elements of said HashMap which satisfy the
comparison function, using the Java 8 Streams-API.
i.e. I want something like this:

```
// pseudo code, this isnt hashmaps work but hopefully it gets the point across
for(int i=0; i<myHashMap.entrySet().length, i++)
  for(int j=i+1, j<myHashMap.entrySet().length) {
    if(myComparison(entrySet.get(i), entrySet.get(j)))
      myList.add(new myClass[] {entrySet.get(i), entrySet.get(j)})
  }
```

But using the streams API. I've a version which almost works using `.forEach` and simply iterating over the stream twice, however this has the issue of running duplicate comparisons and thus adding those duplicates to the list again. I'm fairly certain the `reduce` operator is capable of what I
need but I'm not familiar with Streams API at all and can't figure out how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly you can just construct a set from your map to remove duplicates and then a list from the set.

Comment: @Alex no, the duplicates because with `[a, b, c]` both `a, b` and `b, a` are compared which presumably yields the same result comparing them. This is avoided in the imperative version, since `j` starts from `i+1`, thus it only goes over the rest of the elements, however a `.forEach` always goes over all elements. A set doesn't just fix it, OP to compare all unique pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate all distinct k combinations of the n entries/keys of your map. This post shows how to implement such an algorithm [java-combinations-algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/java-combinations-algorithm). But since I think the task is not to come up with such an algorithm, I would suggest to use a librarry which does that task for you. One of such library is [combinatoricslib3](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib3). If you happen to already use Apache Commons or Guava, they also have implement combinations.

With combinatoricslib3 your code could look like:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.paukov.combinatorics3.Generator;

public class TestJavaClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> myMap = Map.of("Foo", 1, "Bar", 2, "Baz", 3);
        Generator.combination(myMap.keySet())
                .simple(2)
                .stream()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Foo, Baz]
[Foo, Bar]
[Baz, Bar]
```

I have used the key set above to show a simple example. But if you need the entries you can change it to:

```
Generator.combination(myMap.entrySet())...
```

to get the combination of entries:

```
[Foo=1, Baz=3]
[Foo=1, Bar=2]
[Baz=3, Bar=2]
```

Not sure what your `myComparison` method does, but since you use it as a condition in an if statement, I assume it returns a boolean. If so you can use it as a filter to process the stream further. With a dummy implementation of your method `myComparison` and your custom class `MyClass` something like below should give you a starting point:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.paukov.combinatorics3.Generator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

public class TestJavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = Map.of("Foo", 1, "Bar", 2, "Baz", 3);
        List<MyClass> result =
                Generator.combination(myMap.entrySet())
                        .simple(2)
                        .stream()
                        .filter(comb -> myComparison(comb.get(0), comb.get(1)))
                        .map(comb -> new MyClass(comb.get(0), comb.get(1)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static boolean myComparison(Map.Entry<String, Integer> first, Map.Entry<String, Integer> second) {
        return first.getValue() + second.getValue() <= 4;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class MyClass {

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> one;
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> two;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best Answer I've ever received on this site, thanks very much for the wealth of info!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad i could help.